# R: Deleting rows based on a pattern

Tags: r, csv, delete-row

I have the following data frame saved as a .csv which is an output of my previous code. Value1_Cum is the cumulative sum of value 1 for each SAMPLE. It is also available here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16277659/SAMPLE_rs.csv

```
SAMPLE;     ID;     REFERENCE_YEAR; VALUE1; VALUE1_CUM
SAMPLE1;    112;    1956;            0;     0
SAMPLE1;    112;    1957;            200;   200
SAMPLE1;    112;    1958;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE1;    112;    1959;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE1;    112;    1960;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE1;    112;    1963;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1878;            0;     0
SAMPLE2;    137;    1879;          -7900;   -7900
SAMPLE2;    137;    1880;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1881;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1882;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1890;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1891;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1892;         -4300;    -12200
SAMPLE2;    137;    1893;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1894;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1971;            0;     0
SAMPLE3;    136;    1972;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1973;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1974;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1975;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1976;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1980;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE4;    0;      2000;             0;    0
SAMPLE4;    0;      2001;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE4;    0;      2002;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE4;    0;      2003;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE4;    0;      2004;            500;   500
SAMPLE4;    0;      2005;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE4;    0;      2006;            NA;    NA
```

To process the data further I need to delete all the rows for a whole sample which contains the pattern of a 0 and then are followed by NA (in this example SAMPLE3 should get deleted). If a value is between a NA value for the whole SAMPLE (like in SAMPLE2), the rows should be kept. Does anyone have an idea how I could do this?

```
SAMPLE;     ID;     REFERENCE_YEAR; VALUE1; VALUE1_CUM
SAMPLE1;    112;    1956;            0;     0
SAMPLE1;    112;    1957;            200;   200
SAMPLE1;    112;    1958;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE1;    112;    1959;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE1;    112;    1960;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE1;    112;    1963;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1878;            0;     0
SAMPLE2;    137;    1879;          -7900;   -7900
SAMPLE2;    137;    1880;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1881;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1882;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1890;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1891;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1892;         -4300;    -12200
SAMPLE2;    137;    1893;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1894;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE4;    0;      2000;             0;    0
SAMPLE4;    0;      2001;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE4;    0;      2002;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE4;    0;      2003;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE4;    0;      2004;            500;   500
SAMPLE4;    0;      2005;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE4;    0;      2006;            NA;    NA
```

Comment: The ```0``` in ```SAMPLE1;``` appears to be followed by a number, not NA. Why is that one excluded?

Comment: of course you are right! I just copied some data out of my resulting data frame and this was a wrong one, sorry. the only example in here to be deleted should be SAMPLE3.

Comment: Do you mean the zero must be in the column "VALUE1" or "VALUE1_CUM"? Does the zero need to be in a specific column?

Comment: Your header row lacks semicolon separators between all columns, which is going to cause you problems during `read.csv2`/`read.table`.

Comment: out of my resulting data.frame, the zero is always in "VALUE1" and in "VALUE1_CUM", I have one SAMPLE group of ID numbers that  contains 0, i will incorporate it in the sample data. But most important is that only those patterns get deleted that have a 0 and then only NAs followed for the whole SAMPLE. If a number value is inbetween such as in SAMPLE1 and SAMPLE2 then it shouldn't get deleted.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I copied it from a .csv file I wrote out from my R data and have opened in Excel. I corrected the task and I hope it is now clearer what I'd like to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution.

Your data set:

```
df <- structure(list(SAMPLE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("SAMPLE1", "SAMPLE2", 
"SAMPLE3", "SAMPLE4"), class = "factor"), ID = c(112L, 112L, 
112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 
137L, 137L, 137L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), REFERENCE_YEAR = c(1956L, 1957L, 1958L, 
1959L, 1960L, 1963L, 1878L, 1879L, 1880L, 1881L, 1882L, 1890L, 
1891L, 1892L, 1893L, 1894L, 1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 
1976L, 1980L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L
), VALUE1 = c(0, 200, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, -7900, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -4300, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
500, NA, NA), VALUE1_CUM = structure(c(3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("   -7900", "    -12200", 
"     0", "    0", "    NA", "   200", "   500"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("SAMPLE", 
"ID", "REFERENCE_YEAR", "VALUE1", "VALUE1_CUM"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, .SD[!(VALUE1[1] == 0 & (all(is.na(VALUE1[-1]))))], by = SAMPLE]
```

Results

```
# SAMPLE  ID REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE1 VALUE1_CUM
# 1: SAMPLE1 112           1956      0          0
# 2: SAMPLE1 112           1957    200        200
# 3: SAMPLE1 112           1958     NA         NA
# 4: SAMPLE1 112           1959     NA         NA
# 5: SAMPLE1 112           1960     NA         NA
# 6: SAMPLE1 112           1963     NA         NA
# 7: SAMPLE2 137           1878      0          0
# 8: SAMPLE2 137           1879  -7900      -7900
# 9: SAMPLE2 137           1880     NA         NA
#10: SAMPLE2 137           1881     NA         NA
#11: SAMPLE2 137           1882     NA         NA
#12: SAMPLE2 137           1890     NA         NA
#13: SAMPLE2 137           1891     NA         NA
#14: SAMPLE2 137           1892  -4300     -12200
#15: SAMPLE2 137           1893     NA         NA
#16: SAMPLE2 137           1894     NA         NA
#17: SAMPLE4   0           2000      0          0
#18: SAMPLE4   0           2001     NA         NA
#19: SAMPLE4   0           2002     NA         NA
#20: SAMPLE4   0           2003     NA         NA
#21: SAMPLE4   0           2004    500        500
#22: SAMPLE4   0           2005     NA         NA
#23: SAMPLE4   0           2006     NA         NA
#SAMPLE  ID REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE1 VALUE1_CUM
```

Comment: this looks good. but the problem is that it says when applying it, that it could not find setDT function. I have data.table 1.8.8 installed.

Comment: Can you update your `data.table` version by typing `install.packages("data.table")` in console? If not, replace `setDT(df)` with `as.data.table(df)`

Comment: Yes I tried (even uninstalling it and reinstalling, but still says, version 1.8.8). will try your other suggestion, thanks!

Comment: this results in the following error: `[.data.table`(.SD, !(VALUE1[1] == 0 & (all(is.na(VALUE1[-1]))))) : 
  Internal error: notjoin but bywithoutby or !integer or nomatch==NA

Comment: You also need to make sure that `df$VALUE1` is of `numeric` type and contains real `NA`s (not characters). The best way of doing this is to run  `df$VALUE1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$VALUE1))` first

Comment: Ok, I've posted the data set I've used. The code works flawless. If it doesn't work for you, the problem is on your end. What version of R do you use btw?

Comment: sorry that I've been bothering you, I got it to work. I am using an old version on Mac OSX 10.8.5 and I was unable to update it. Tried it on my windows partition with an newer version and it worked flawlessly! Thanks a lot for baring with me!!

Comment: Try removing your package first by using `remove.packages()` and then in a clean session installing the package again..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply subset your dataset with a multitudes of methods after observing the following output. We first find the positions of 0s in 1:n-1 positions in the vector, then check if the 0 positions+1 is NA. (I manually added a few ; in the table header for reading purposes)

```
by(data = df, INDICES = df$SAMPLE,
   FUN = function(x) any(is.na(x$VALUE1[which((x$VALUE1)[1:(length(x$VALUE1)-1)] == 0)+1])))

df$SAMPLE: SAMPLE1
[1] FALSE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$SAMPLE: SAMPLE2
[1] FALSE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$SAMPLE: SAMPLE3
[1] TRUE


x = "SAMPLE;     ID;      REFERENCE_YEAR;  VALUE1; VALUE1_CUM
SAMPLE1;    112;    1956;            0;     0
SAMPLE1;    112;    1957;            200;   200
SAMPLE1;    112;    1958;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE1;    112;    1959;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE1;    112;    1960;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE1;    112;    1963;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1878;            0;     0
SAMPLE2;    137;    1879;          -7900;   -7900
SAMPLE2;    137;    1880;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1881;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1882;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1890;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1891;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1892;         -4300;    -12200
SAMPLE2;    137;    1893;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE2;    137;    1894;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1971;            0;    -500
SAMPLE3;    136;    1972;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1973;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1974;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1975;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1976;            NA;    NA
SAMPLE3;    136;    1980;            NA;    NA"

df = read.table(text = x, sep = ";", header = TRUE, colClasses= c("character", rep("numeric", 4)))
```

Edited with output with sample 4 data

```
df$SAMPLE: SAMPLE1
[1] FALSE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$SAMPLE: SAMPLE2
[1] FALSE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$SAMPLE: SAMPLE3
[1] TRUE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$SAMPLE: SAMPLE4
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: this is working for the previous version, but when having another column with 0 (like ID in SAMPLE4, it doesn't work). I changed the sample file.

Comment: Works fine for me. See edit for output. I read in the data the exact same way.

Comment: I get the same output but SAMPLE4 shouldn't get deleted because it also contains a number in between! What I'd like to do is that when there is a zero at the beginning of the sample in VALUE1 and VALUE1_CUM followed by a NA and then the rest for the whole column followed by NAs that it only gets deleted under these conditions (such as in SAMPLE3) not when there is a number in between (500 in SAMPLE4). But thank you very much for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution, using the `dput()` supplied by @David

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(SAMPLE) %>%
    filter(! (VALUE1[[1]] == 0 & all(is.na(VALUE1[-1])) ) )
```

obtaining

```
    SAMPLE  ID REFERENCE_YEAR VALUE1 VALUE1_CUM
1  SAMPLE1 112           1956      0          0
2  SAMPLE1 112           1957    200        200
3  SAMPLE1 112           1958     NA         NA
4  SAMPLE1 112           1959     NA         NA
5  SAMPLE1 112           1960     NA         NA
6  SAMPLE1 112           1963     NA         NA
7  SAMPLE2 137           1878      0          0
8  SAMPLE2 137           1879  -7900      -7900
9  SAMPLE2 137           1880     NA         NA
10 SAMPLE2 137           1881     NA         NA
11 SAMPLE2 137           1882     NA         NA
12 SAMPLE2 137           1890     NA         NA
13 SAMPLE2 137           1891     NA         NA
14 SAMPLE2 137           1892  -4300     -12200
15 SAMPLE2 137           1893     NA         NA
16 SAMPLE2 137           1894     NA         NA
17 SAMPLE4   0           2000      0          0
18 SAMPLE4   0           2001     NA         NA
19 SAMPLE4   0           2002     NA         NA
20 SAMPLE4   0           2003     NA         NA
21 SAMPLE4   0           2004    500        500
22 SAMPLE4   0           2005     NA         NA
23 SAMPLE4   0           2006     NA         NA
```